# Visual Studio (Intellisense) no operator std::ostringstream <<

Tags: c++, visual-studio, intellisense, esp32, visualmicro

I am using Visual Studio 16.5.3 with visual micro plugin (Release 20.03.21.2/3) to compile some ESP32 board sketches. I get a tedious error from the IDE, **even tho the code compiles and runs fine**. The relevant lines are:

```
std::ostringstream ss;
ss << "LIGHT: ";
```

I included `<iostream>, <string>, <sstream> and <ostream>`

The **IDE is complaining about missing << operator**, with operands of type `std::stringstream` and `const char[8]`. The actual message is (sorry for italian, I guess it's clear anyway):

"C++ nessun operatore corrispondente agli operandi i tipi di operando sono: std::ostringstream << const char [8]"

That would sound something like "no operator << for the operands..."

Comment: Also, please post error messages in English.

Comment: How does it compile and work if you are getting a compiler error?  Are you compiling code that will run on a ESP32 microcontroller?

Comment: have you even read my question? I'm saying only Visual Studio is reporting the error, the actual compilation and linking works

Comment: Yes, I've read it but it's unclear, that's why I'm asking follow up questions.  So is the issue that you are getting a red squiggly line under the line of code?

Comment: yes, it bothers me as I can't distinguish from 'real' errors

Comment: @Shine - I think what you really mean to say is that "Intellisense is broken for the stringstream stream operator".  Someone adequately described it the other day on a question - since the intellisense parser has to run fast and in the background, it can't completely validate everything the compiler itself will find. As such, there are plenty of false positives and false negatives with Intellisense. It's par for the course with Visual Studio to have such issues.

Comment: Visual Micro is a commercial product, they should be able to provide support on this.

Comment: Annoying, yes. But there's not much you can do about it.  sometimes doing a "clean" followed by closing and re-opening the project fixes these issues. Other times not.

Comment: @Shine Okay.  What you have is an Intellisense issue.  I can't help you with that, but now you can update the question with that information so people who do know have a chance of finding it.

Comment: thank you @selbie, I would accept a solution to (partially?) disable those check, as I am Eclipse user and I do not know Visual Studio very much. Could it be related to the microcontroller plugin I am using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Visual Studio (Intellisense) no operator std::ostringstream <<

**First**, you should put the below code under function or main body and then import several head file as you showed above.

Like this:

[image]

So if you still face the issue and build the project without any errors, I think it is Intellisense's problem. And you can see that it works well in my side. And you can try this：

**Suggestion**:

**1)** close VS Instance, delete `.vs` hidden folder, `bin`, `obj` folder and then reopen your project again.

**2)** disable any unrelated third-party extensions under `Extensions`-->`Manage Extensions` or use [devenv /safemode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/safemode-devenv-exe?view=vs-2019) to start VS to test whether it is caused by other extensions.

**In addition**, if this issue still persists, please share the sample code with us so that we can troubleshoot it as soon as possible.

Any feedback will be expected.

Comment: cleaning files nor disabling extensions solved the issue. BUT creating a new empty project and using your code does not show any error.